# Using the pivot option in matplotlib quiver3d

Tags: matplotlib, plot

Is the pivot option (where to anchor the vector field arrows) unsupported in quiver 3d matplotlib?  I get`AttributeError: Unknown property pivot` when I try to use it.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind.  The pivot feature is in MPL 1.5.1, and I had been trying to do this on a 1.4.1 machine which didn't have it.  It works as desired.